# c++ time() function performance in solaris

Tags: c++, performance, time, solaris

We have a multi-threaded C++ application running on **Solaris (5.10, sparc platform)**. As per "pstack" most of the threads seem to be waiting on the below call often for little too long. This corresponds to "`time_t currentTime = time(NULL) ;`" function in the application code to get the current time in seconds.

```
ffffffff76cdbe1c __time (0, 23e8, 1dab58, ffffffff76c63508, ffffffff76e3e000, 2000) + 8
```

The timezone is "**Asia/Riyadh**". I tried setting the TZ variable to both "Asia/Riyadh" as well as '`<GMT+3>-3`'. But there is no obvious improvement with either option. Changing the server code (even if there is an alternative) is rather difficult at this point. A test program (single thread, compiled without -O2) having 1 million "`time(NULL)`" invocations came out rather quickly. The application & test program are compiled using `gcc 4.5.1`.

Is there anything else that I can try out?

I agree that it is a rather broad question. I will try out the valid suggestions and close this as soon as there is adequate improvement to handle current load.

**Edit 1 :**

Please ignore the reference to time(NULL) above, as a possible cause for __time stack. I made the inference based on the signature, and finding the same invocation in the source method.

Following is another stack leading to __time.

```
ffffffff76cdbe1c __time (0, 23e8, 1dab58, ffffffff773e5cc0, ffffffff76e3e000, 2000) + 8
ffffffff76c9c7f0 getnow (ffffffff704fb180, ffffffff773c6384, 1a311c, 2, ffffffff76e4eae8, fffc00) + 4
ffffffff76c9af0c strptime_recurse (ffffffff76e4cea0, 1, 104980178,   ffffffff704fb938, ffffffff704fb180, ffffffff704fb1a4) + 34
ffffffff76c9dce8 __strptime_std (ffffffff76e4cea0, 10458b2d8, 104980178, ffffffff704fb938, 2400, 1a38ec) + 2c
```

Comment: The time zone has no impact on the return value of `time()`, at least under Unix.  It's always UTC.

Comment: You should provide more evidence `time` is really the culprit. `truss -c command` or dtrace `procsystime -aTn yourApp` output would help. By the way, setting TZ has no effect whatsoever on the time call itself. (edit: too late for this latter comment ...)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'd be surprised that the compiler optimized out calls to `time`.  It's an external function, whose behavior the compiler can't see, and so the compiler must assume that it might have observable behavior.

Comment: I think I am wrong about the actual function leading to above stack. I see a localtime() call as well in the method below the time() call, which I assume is dependent on TZ. I tried changing TZ based on a similar issue we faced long back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (and we) are not going to be able to make `time` faster.
From your message, I gather that you are calling it from many
different threads at once.  This may be a problem; it's quite
possible that Solaris serializes these calls, so you end up with
a lot of threads waiting for the others to complete.

How much accuracy do you need?  A possible solution might be to
have one thread loop on reading the time, sleeping maybe 10 ms
between each read, and putting the results in a global variable,
which the other threads read.  (Don't forget that you'll need to
synchronize all accesses to the variable, *unless* you have some
sort of atomic variables, like `std::atomic<time_t>` in C++11.)

Comment: Yes, it is called from multiple threads. Accuracy is very important. Also I am not in a position to change the server code either unfortunately at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `pstack` doesn't just immediately interrupt your program and generate a stack. It has to grab debug-level control and if `time` calls are sufficiently frequent it may drastically over-indicate calls to `time` as it utilizes those syscalls to take control of your application to print the stack.

Most likely the `time` calls are not the source of your real performance problem. I suspect you'll want to utilize a profiler such as `gprof` (with `g++ -p`). Alternately you could utilize some of the dtrace kits and use the `hotuser` dtrace script which will do basic statistical profiling on your running application's user code.

`time` returns UTC time so any changes to `TZ` should have no effect on its call time whatsoever.

If, after profiling, it turns out that `time` really is the culprit you may be able to cache the value from the `time` call since it won't change more than once a second.

Comment: pstack observation is based on past few day's snapshots. There are time related calls at different parts of code. pstack almost always shows __time, though from different methods in our code. There is considerable amount of other operations in the code, which do not appear often in the pstack. Profiling would require recompilation (this issue is observed in production machine). Regarding TZ, as mentioned above, I might be wrong about the time() call. There is a localtime() call as well. I am not sure about this though.